# How do I do parallel mapreduce in julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, julia, distributed-computing

How do I do parallel mapreduce in julia?
I have seen the `mapreduce` function, but it is not parallel/distributed.

Say I want what is the largest remainder from trying to divide 33333331 by a  number ≤ 16666665.

This can be done as:

```
julia> mapreduce(x-> rem(33333331, x), max, 1:16666665)
11111109
```

In this contrived example that runs fine without parallelism.
But I am interested in doing it in parallel

Answer (score 4):

That can be done via `@parallel for`

[manual says](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.0/stdlib/parallel/#Base.Distributed.@parallel):

> #### Base.Distributed.@parallel — Macro.
>
> ```
> @parallel [reducer] for var = range
>     body
>   end
> ```
>
> The specified range is partitioned and locally executed across all workers. In case an optional reducer function is specified, @parallel performs local reductions on each worker with a final reduction on the calling process.

So your code becomes

```
julia> @parallel max for x in 1:16666665
              rem(33333331, x)
       end
11111109
```

I don't do not like the parallel for loop, but it does the job
It is such a problematic syntax, since for-loops don't normally have (meaningful) return values, this one does, it uses the return values of it loops content

One can hide it, with something that (if I've not screwed up) matches how `Base.mapreduce` works

```
julia> function pmapreduce(mapfun, redfun, iters...)
           @parallel redfun for arg in collect(zip(iters...))
                  mapfun(arg...)
           end
       end
pmapreduce (generic function with 1 method)

julia> pmapreduce(x-> rem(33333331, x), max, 1:16666665)
11111109
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late, but there is the package [ThreadsX](https://github.com/tkf/ThreadsX.jl) that provides a parallel implementation of `mapreduce`.